# How to specify relative path to a file inside init.el

Tags: init-file, filenames

I have something like this inside my init file:

```
(when (file-readable-p "/absolute/path/to/config.org")
      (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "/absolute/path/to/config.org")))
```

Where `config.org` is in the same directory as `init.el`. I want to be able to specify a relative path to `init.el` so that emacs can find the config file no matter where the init file is located on any device. However, when I tried `"./config.org"` that is interpreted relative to the directory where emacs is opened, not where `init.el` is located.

How can I specify a path relative to `init.el`?

I'm using emacs-28, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

When your init file is loaded, the current directory, that is, the value of variable **`default-directory`**, is the directory where your init file is, by default. That is, that's the value unless your init file does something that changes `default-directory`.

So you can just use the value of `default-directory`.

For example if you use a function that accepts a file name without the directory part, then just use the file name without the directory part, and `default-directory` will be understood.

Or if you use a function that needs an absolute file name, then use `expand-file-name` without specifying optional arg `DEFAULT-DIRECTORY` (or passing it as `nil`).

E.g.:

```lisp
(when (file-readable-p "config.org")
  (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "config.org")))
```

which is the same as:

```lisp
(when (file-readable-p (expand-file-name "config.org"))
  (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "config.org")))
```

which is the same as:

```lisp
(when (file-readable-p (expand-file-name "config.org" default-directory))
  (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "config.org" default-directory)))
```